# Drawing rectangle on ImageView - not drawing upwards/leftwards

Tags: java, android, touch-event, ondraw

I've created a class which extends the ImageView allowing me to draw rectangles onto the ImageView on touch.

I can draw rectangles however they only display when I'm dragging the rectangle from the starting point downward and to the right.

If I drag the rectangle from the starting point upwards or to the left then no rectangle is drawn. OnDraw() fires but nothing displays.

My class:

```
public class TagImageView extends ImageView {

    private float downX;
    private float downY;
    private float upX;
    private float upY;
    private Paint paint;

    public TagImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);   
        init();
    }

    public TagImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);     
        init();
    }

    public TagImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   
            downX = event.getX();
            downY = event.getY();
            invalidate();            

            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            upX = event.getX();
            upY = event.getY();
            invalidate();

            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            invalidate();

            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }      

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRect(downX, downY, upX, upY, paint);
    }
}
```

Edit: Not sure if this is relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24168545/2380071

Comment: can you debug and check wat values are present in `downX` `downY` `upX` `upY` during `onDraw`. Or simple write  `Log.d` inside `onDraw` method and check the values

Comment: Yeah they seem valid, in a case where nothing was drawn: 591, 1225, 274, 965. In a case where the rectangle is drawn, downX < upX and downY < upY.

Comment: The `downX` and `downY` is the `startX` and `startY` for the rectangle. I believe this should be always greater than the `endX` and `endY` which in your case is `upX` and `upY` Try to pass `canvas.drawRect(upX, upY,downX, downY, paint);` if `upX` and `upY` is `>` than `downX` and `downY`. Hope this works

Comment: Thanks @Panther for your advice. If I implemented your suggestion then I believe I would encounter the same problem if I were to draw the rectangle from the starting point downward and to the right (meaning upX > downX or upY > downY). I believe I have to put in checks to see if downX and downY are less than or greater than upX and upY then handle accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just ended up modifying my `OnDraw()` method to check the values of the downX, downY and upX, upY points. Trivial, really... although not sure if it's the most efficient. Welcome to any suggestions (or, er.. pointers)!

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (downX < upX && downY < upY)
        canvas.drawRect(downX, downY, upX, upY, paint);
    else if (downX > upX && downY < upY)
        canvas.drawRect(upX, downY, downX, upY, paint);
    else if (downX < upX && downY > upY)
        canvas.drawRect(downX, upY, upX, downY, paint);
    else
        canvas.drawRect(upX, upY, downX, downY, paint);
}
```

Comment: make sure you dont have any other layer on image otherwise that will return wrong position